# How to map PageDown to Option?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have not been able to figure out how to map <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to <kbd>Option</kbd>. I have KeyRemap4MacBook installed, but the options they have in the "Change Key" pane don't allow me to do this.

How can I map <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to <kbd>Option</kbd>?

Comment: I have a Kinesis Advantage, there is no Option or Alt key on the right side for the thumb. There are PageUp/Down keys, so I want to use them as Option/Alt. Given the unusual layout of the Kinesis, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: OHHHH i totally thought you meant you wanted to turn option into page down lol. My bad >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving something like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, KeyCode::OPTION_L, VK_OPTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

I'm not sure, but it might not work if you don't have another keyboard with an option key connected.

If `KeyCode::PAGEDOWN` doesn't work, you can see the [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) in the source and the hexadecimal key codes with [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/).

The test folder has an [XML file](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true) with all the predefined remappings.